# Número total de elementos em uma pilha

Tags: c

Quero saber como faço para retornar na tela o número total de elementos em uma pilha.
Por exemplo: tenho uma pilha vetor de tamanho 10 e empilhei 6 elementos nela, terá que me retornar o total de 6 elementos.

Tenho esse código aqui, mas não está me retornando corretamente:

```
void pilha_imprime (tipo_pilha *pilha)
{
   int i;
   for (i=pilha->topo-1; i>=0; i--)
      printf(“%f\n”, pilha->pilha[i]);
   return i;      //tem retorno i??
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Método genérico para retorno de elementos em pilha:

```
//Count the number of items in the stack
int countitem()
{
    ListElem *i;
    int t=0;
    i=pfirst; //point to the first item then move it to the next

    while(i!=NULL){
       t=t+1; //increment
       i=i->next;
     }

    return t; //return the number of item counted
}
```